# Zend - How pass values from API (class) to controller?

Tags: api, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-controller

If I build a custom API (class) and want to pass the values obtained from an API call to my controller, how do I do that?  Usually I have do this in my controller:

```
$form = new Application_My_Form();
$model = new Application_My_Model($form->getValues());
```

But since I'm not using a form and there isn't a view, then how do I post/pass the values from my API to the controller's action?  Is there a better way to pass an array of values from my API class to a controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your API is built within your ZF application?  And you are within the controller for your API?  You can access input parameters using

```
$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

which will give you an associative array of supplied parameters.

Comment: I have the API class in my Zend application custom library.  I'm not within the controller, but trying to pass values from my API class to a Zend controller.  Thanks for supplying the statement to use within my controller, now, what would the statement look like in the API class?  How do I pass those "params" from the class to the controller?

Comment: From outside the controller, you can use `Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getParams();`, if you need to pass values from API to controller, then just make them available via the instance of the API class you have in your controller?

Comment: Sorry, I'm probably not explaining this correctly...I think I have a grasp now on how to get the params in my controller - as you pointed out `$params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();`  But now how do I "set" the params in the api class so that they're available to grab?

Comment: Is this what I need to use?  `$this->getRequest()->setParams($values);`